# Cannot call a method with a type after an instanceof check

Tags: java

I have a list of groceries in which I stored some foods and beverages. Grocery is an abstract class and both Food and Beverage extend it.

I created a static method inside Grocery to save a list of groceries in a file. This method scans the whole list and, for each of its elements, it should call the saveToFile method inside the Food class if the element is a food, or the saveToFile method inside the Beverage class if the element is a beverage.

```
public static void saveListToFile(ArrayList<Grocery> groceries) {
    for(int i = 0; i < groceries.size(); i++) {
        if(groceries.get(i) instanceof Food) {
            Food.saveToFile(groceries.get(i));
        }
        else
            Beverage.saveToFile(groceries.get(i));
    }
}
```

This does not compile. Instead I get the following error: *The method saveToFile() in the type Food is not applicable for the arguments (Grocery).*

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is the problem you are facing? The above code does hardly provide any context.

Comment: If there's a `saveToFile()` method on `Grocery`, why aren't you just calling it? The whole point of polymorphism is that the underlying object knows its own type and will invoke the correct implementation.

Comment: Well, I think I've explained pretty well what I'm trying to do in the description I wrote. This is the error i get: The method saveToFile() in the type Food is not applicable for the arguments (Grocery).

Comment: It could be that you have to cast the result of `groceries.get(i)` to `Food` or `Beverage`: `Food.saveToFile((Food) groceries.get(i))`. Unfortunately, you did not post your compiler's error message or the declaration of `Food.saveToFile`/`Beverage.saveToFile`

Comment: @stoneburner: I did update your question with the error message (that helps people who answer enormously). I also removed the "I am a noob" part - everybody has to start somewhere, and others who have the same problem are going to find your question easier.

Comment: If you face situation like `Parent.someMethod(Parent p);` then probably `someMethod` shouldn't be static and instead be called like `p.someMethod()` which also enable polymorphism allowing ChildA and ChildB to provide their own implementations for that method and even if under `p` we will pass instance of some ChildX its version of `someMethod` would be called eliminating need for `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2):

Try casting it as soon as you check its type, eg :

```
if (groceries.get(i) instanceof Food) {
   Food.saveToFile((Food)groceries.get(i));
}
else
   Beverage.saveToFile((Beverage)groceries.get(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

As [azurefrog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1361506/azurefrog) suggested, I wrote an abstract saveToFile method inside Grocery:

```
public abstract void saveToFile();
```

Then I rewrote the saveListToFile like this:

```
public static void saveListToFile(ArrayList<Grocery> groceries) {
    for(Grocery item: groceries)
        item.saveToFile();
}
```

This way it works since it uses polymorphism and runs the proper method inside the proper class for every item.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are learning in a classroom, it is quite possible that this implementation via polymorphism is shown after your manual `instanceof` check - in order to demonstrate the usefulness of polymporphism instead of manual checks.

Answer (score 1):

The part of your code using instanceof is correctly doing what you want (even if it's bad practice.

If your code is not compiling with the error " The method saveToFile() in the type Food is not applicable for the arguments (Grocery)." that is means yours method saveToFile take in parameter a Food or a Beverage and not a Grocery. You need to cast the item before applying the method. (If i am right supposing the content of the class Food and Beverage that is missing here)

```
public static void saveListToFile(ArrayList<Grocery> groceries) {
for(int i = 0; i < groceries.size(); i++) {
    if(groceries.get(i) instanceof Food) {
        Food.saveToFile((Food)groceries.get(i));
    }
    else
        Beverage.saveToFile((Beverage)groceries.get(i));
  }
}
```

I don't know your exact need but I think you could design a much better solution using inheritance. saveToFile does not have to be necessary static. You could have 2 differents implementation in Food and Beverage and for example each of the both implementation could write in a specific file using a static fonction comming from an other class.